# Using sticky load balance apache, application context is being lost

Tags: java, apache, unix, tomcat

Below is the sticky load balancing configuration of Apache2. It is properly doing stickyness and load balancing.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Location "/balancer-manager">
        SetHandler balancer-manager
    </Location>
    ServerName 10.10.87.177
Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
<Proxy "balancer://mycluster">
    AddDefaultCharset off
        Order deny,allow
        allow from all
    BalancerMember "ajp://10.10.87.177:8009/myapp" route=node1
    BalancerMember "ajp://10.10.87.241:8009/myapp" route=node2
    #ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
     ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid
</Proxy>
ProxyPass "/myapp" "balancer://mycluster" 
ProxyPassReverse "/myapp" "balancer://mycluster"
</VirtualHost>
```

But problem is that when i am hittitng  `http://10.10.87.177/myapp`, response is correct as `home page`. but when i am submitting the home page, it action is t.jsp, the server hitting url is `http://t.jsp?param1=val1`. Here i am loosing the context **/myapp**, don't know the reason. The hitting url should be `http://10.10.87.177/myapp/t.jsp?param1=val1`

Please help me resolve the issue.

Here is the html:

```
<form action="t.jsp">Enter your name: <input type="text" name="name">
<p>
<input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

If i am accessing application without load balancer, it is working fine but when using load balancer as configured above is loosing the context.

Comment: Can we see the HTML of the form that you're submitting?

Comment: @mhlz i posted the html code also.

Answer (score 0):

Make below changes in your code :

BalancerMember "ajp://10.10.87.177:8009/myapp/" route=node1
BalancerMember "ajp://10.10.87.241:8009/myapp/" route=node2

ProxyPass "/myapp/" "balancer://mycluster/" 
ProxyPassReverse "/myapp/" "balancer://mycluster/"

-VV